# What do you do when you're filled with uncertainty about a problem?

Tags: proof-writing, problem-solving

I'm currently trying to prove a conjecture.

I know that the proof will have to consist of multiple sub-lemmas, and that I need to make at least one additional assumption in the conjecture for it to be even possibly true. (With the current assumptions i've proven it false).

I'm convinced that the conjecture is true  if I make additional assumptions, because I have a number of special cases that satisfy it and they seem very clearly generalizable.

I've been working on different assumptions and different approaches to the problem, and I've generally made progress. **But I'm now filled with lots of messy ideas and subresults and I don't have an overview of the problem.**

But my question is not about this particular problem. My question is: **what do you do when youre working on a problem where you know that you need to use extra assumptions and sub-results but you don't know which ones, and youre generally overwhelmed and uncertain about the possibilities?**

Comment: I don't think that anyone can help if you don't show more details of the problem you are dealing with. You should at least post which conjecture it is. As written, the question is way too broad.

Comment: Taking a break from it and/or working on something else for a while is probably a good idea. This may help with the ideas 'settling' and being 'processed' by your mind. You may 'realise' things while not trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ask an academic advisor or  a knowledgeable friend to give me ideas or to check out my work.

Collaborating is a good virtue when your are overwhelmed and tired.